# Python Turtle Enumerate

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Is anyone able to explain this code? My friend wrote it and I don’t understand anything about the line defining “diff”

```
import math
import turtle
import random

t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()
t.shape("turtle")
t.speed(0)
t.tracer(100)

COLOR = [18.0, 0.0, 41.0]
COLOR_2 = [0.0, 172.0, 219.0]
WIDTH = screen.window_width()
HEIGHT = screen.window_height()

diff = [(hue - COLOR[index]) / HEIGHT for index, hue in enumerate(COLOR_2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to evenly distribute values from `COLOR` to `COLOR_2` over `HEIGHT` steps, this would compute how much to change each component at each step.  For example, if `HEIGHT` were 2, it would compute `[-9.0, 86.0, 89.0]`.

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate(COLOR_2)` returns an `enumerate` object where the first variable is the index of the item in the list and the second variable is the actual item. Then the `for` loop loops through these results, so for the list `COLOR_2` the first iteration will give: `index = 0` and `hue = 0.0`, and so on: `index = 1`, `hue = 172.0` etc. So for each iteration it evaluates `(hue - COLOR[index]) / HEIGHT` which, for the first iteration, is: `(0.0 - COLOR[0]) / screen.window_height()` Since this generator of sorts is in list brakets `[]` it is a list comprehension and thus creates a list where each item is the formula: `(hue - COLOR[index]) / HEIGHT` evaluated at each value pair (explained earlier) from `index, hue in enumerate(COLOR_2)`.

For further understanding the code is equivalent to:

```
diff = []
for index, hue in enumerate(COLOR_2):
    diff.append((hue - COLOR[index]) / HEIGHT)
```

Another simplification:

```
for i, item in enumerate(lst): #this is the same as:

for item in lst: #this

#the only difference is that the second option does not have a 
#variable that loops through the indices (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.)
```

Therefore, since your code needs `COLOR[index]` (so that the items in `COLOR` are linked with the items in `COLOR_2`) you need to use `enumerate` so that you also get the `index` since it is needed.

The output (value of `diff`) given a `HEIGHT` of 800 (for example) should be:

```
[-0.0225, 0.215, 0.2225]
```

Based on my understanding of the purpose of this code, you could then increment from `COLOR` to `COLOR_2` by `diff` to create a "gradient" or "Ombre effect".